# How would I solve this integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that I have to integrate both sides, but how would I integrate the right side? For context purposes, this came from the derivation of a curve, so I know this must end in a curve. $s$ is a constant and can be treated as such. $f(x)$ is not solely the function of $x$, but actually a constant as well. How would I integrate this?

$$f'(x)=\frac{s\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{s^2-2f(x)s\sqrt{7}+f(x)^2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for $f(x)$ being a function both of $x$ and a constant, that doesn't affect the solution method to use. Instead, note you have a separable equation. In particular, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{df(x)}{dx} & = \frac{s\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{s^2-2f(x)s\sqrt{7}+f(x)^2}} \\
\left(\sqrt{s^2-2f(x)s\sqrt{7}+f(x)^2}\right)d(f(x)) & = \left(\frac{s\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)dx
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

With the factor on the right, you can complete the square inside the square root to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(x)^2 - 2f(x)s\sqrt{7} + s^2 & = (f(x) - s\sqrt{7})^2 - 7s^2 + s^2 \\
& = (f(x) - s\sqrt{7})^2 - 6s^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

I will leave it to you do some manipulations, including using an appropriate substitution (e.g., such as asked and shown at Quora's https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-integrate-sqrt-x-2-a-2-with-respect-to-x or in the [Integrals containing $x^2 - a^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Integrals_containing_x2_%E2%88%92_a2) section of Wikipedia's "Trigonometric substitution" article), to integrate the right side.

Comment: Well actually I am only in Calculus 1 so this is a really difficult problem for me regardless. Could I do some sort of hyperbolic substitution? That was originally supposed to be my final function anyway so I'm assuming that's what your suppoed to do.

Comment: @AnishShah The $2$ links I provided basically show how you can solve your problem. The first one shows using integration by parts (including using a trigonometric substitution) and the second one shows how you can use just a trigonometric substitution. I don't see offhand how you can solve it using a hyperbolic substitution. I suggest you use one of those $2$ other methods unless you can find or come up with a better one yourself.